# Vue 3 Composition API Script Setup "ref" with object and types

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am moving from Vue2 to Vue3 but couldn't manage to transfer some objects to new [ref method](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref).

How do I write this with ref with types?
I did some research but couldn't find much.

```
 data() {
    return {
      isDeleteEnabled: true,
      contractSet: {
        contract: {
          id: null,
          name:''
          is_deleted: null,
          created_datetime: '',
        },
        services: [
          {
            id: null,
            name: '',
            is_disabled: null,
            is_deleted: null,
          },
        ],
      } as ContractSetsType,
    };
  },
```

Started like this but it gives type errors: (No overload matches this call)

```
    let isDeleteEnabled= ref<boolean>(false); // This works fine

    // This gives type error
    let contractSet = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
              id: null,
            },
    });
```

My ContractSetsType:

```
 export interface ContractSetsType {
        /**
         * 
         * @type {Contract}
         * @memberof ContractSetsType
         */
        contract?: Contract;
    }
    
    export interface Contract {
        /**
         * 契約id
         * @type {number}
         * @memberof Contract
         */
        id: number;
    
        /**
         * 契約名
         * @type {string}
         * @memberof Contract
         */
        name: string;
    
        /**
         * 削除済フラグ
         * @type {boolean}
         * @memberof Contract
         */
        is_deleted: boolean;
    
        /**
         * 作成日時
         * @type {string}
         * @memberof Contract
         */
        created_datetime: string;
    }
```

Should I use reactive instead of ref?

Comment: How is your `ContractSetsType` defined?

Comment: @cSharp added above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ContractSetsType` is different from below.

```js
{
    contract: {
        id: null    
    }
}
```

You have to match the type:

```js
//below works fine
let contractSet = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
        id: 12,
        name: "my name",
        is_deleted: false,
        created_datetime: "timestamp string"
    }
})

let contractSet0 = ref<ContractSetsType>({
})

// below doesn't work
let contractSet1 = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
        id: 12,
        name: "my name",
    }
})

let contractSet2 = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
        id: 12,
    }
})

let contractSet3 = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
        id: null
    }
})
```

If you want

```js
let contractSet = ref<ContractSetsType>({
    contract: {
        id: null
    }
})
```

to work, you could change `interface Contract` to have everything optional.

Comment: I added the wrong types. Sorry. Could you take a look at the code again?

Comment: Still, you have to match your correct types. Edited answer to give examples.